# Subclassing UICollectionReusableView: reference to "content area"

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, subclass

I'm trying to subclass `UICollectionReusableView` to simplify some code. I'm running into a problem of what to "add the view to" once it is built.

Here is an example of what I want to do, using UICollectionViewCell as an example:

```
class CVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let textLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        let textFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: textFrame)

        super.init(frame: frame)

        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        contentView.addSubview(textLabel)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    ...

    }
}
```

Here, when I'm ready to add the `UILabel`, I add it to the contentView. I can't seem to find a parallel subview to `UICollectionReusableView` to refer to. So I write this and get to the last line and I'm not sure what to put where I have the placeholder "ConfusionHere":

```
class CVHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

    let textLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        let textSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        textLabel = UILabel(frame: textSize)

        super.init(frame: frame)
        textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
        textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        ConfusionHere.addSubview(textLabel)
}
```

I'm probably missing some concept here, but I've searched the docs and have found no parallel to "contentView" for the `UICollectionReusableView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply do self.addSubView(textLabel)

```
class CVHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

let textLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    let textSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
    textLabel = UILabel(frame: textSize)

    super.init(frame: frame)
    textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10)
    textLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    self.addSubview(textLabel) // confusion removed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple. I don't think to use self in Swift.